# Enable Postgres PDO module for PHP 5 on Ubuntu to work with Laravel

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, ubuntu, pdo

I've spent some hours trying to change the connection driver of my Laravel app from MySQL to Postgres. I'm working with Laravel 5.2 on a Ubuntu 14 (and PHP 5.5.9).

I had Postgres installed in this computer before starting it all. The version I got is 9.3.12.

The problem I'm having is that when my App uses the database it throws an error:

> PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
>
> could not find driver

In PHPInfo it says

> PDO Drivers:     mysql

And running `php -m` I don't see anything related to Postgres.

So it seems it's not installed in my computer, but everytime I try to install these modules I get errors, usually related to dependencies.

What is the proper way to get Postgres installed for PHP5?

**@edit**

With the suggested command `sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql` I get a message (in my language) that is similar to the following:

> The following packages have not found dependencies
>
> php5-pgsql : Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4) but 
>   5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14 is installed
>
> E: Impossible to fix problems, you kept (hold) broken packages.

Comment: http://php.net/pdo_pgsql

Comment: Where do I get the source files then?

Comment: From php.net http://php.net/downloads.php#v5.6.25

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql` This will install and enable the `pdo_pgsql` extension for PHP.

Comment: @marekful read my edit, please

Comment: It seems you have broken package dependencies, likely following a failed upgrade/install. Did you install PHP from the official Ubuntu package repository (using apt-get)? Try `sudo apt-get install -f` to fix dependencies. If that fails, try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` first.